# Catching an exception caused by 'finally' while raising a preceeding exception

Tags: python-3.x, exception

Let's say I have the following code:

```
def do(i):
    try:
        1/i
    except:
        raise
    finally:
        raise NotImplementedError
```

It will try to divide 1 by a certain number, and will then in its finally clause, raise an Exception. What if I wanted to handle the exception in `finally`, but still want exceptions from `try` to be raised? (Note that I can't change how `do` works. I need to wrap `do`within my own exception handling logic).

To illustrate, let's try a few things:

```
do(1)

>>>

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-bf2a92c9df1e> in <module>
----> 1 do(1)

<ipython-input-14-17793ae783da> in do(i)
      5         raise
      6     finally:
----> 7         raise NotImplementedError

NotImplementedError:
```

,

```
do(0)

>>>

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-17793ae783da> in do(i)
      2     try:
----> 3         1/i
      4     except:

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-dcdf66fecd31> in <module>
----> 1 do(0)

<ipython-input-14-17793ae783da> in do(i)
      5         raise
      6     finally:
----> 7         raise NotImplementedError

NotImplementedError:
```

,

```
try:
    do(0)
except NotImplementedError:
    print("passed")
except:
    raise

>>>
passed
```

So, it is catching the NotImplementedError, which happens while handling the ZeroDivisionError and is therefore not raising ZeroDivisionError .

Comment: The last example seems to do what the title of the question asks for, no?

Comment: No, the last example should throw a ZeroDivisionError

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement), emphasis is mine:

> If finally is present, it specifies a ‘cleanup’ handler. The try
> clause is executed, including any except and else clauses. If an
> exception occurs in any of the clauses and is not handled, the
> exception is temporarily saved. The finally clause is executed. If
> there is a saved exception it is re-raised at the end of the finally
> clause. **If the finally clause raises another exception, the saved
> exception is set as the context of the new exception.** If the finally
> clause executes a return, break or continue statement, the saved
> exception is discarded.

My addition to the emphasised part: otherwise the context is set to `None`.

In other words, the code that calls `do(0)` can't directly catch `ZeroDevisionError` since it is being masked by the `NotImplementedError` raised by the `finally` block. It will have to explicitly check the context of the `NotImplemented` exception.

```
try:
    do(0)
except NotImplementedError as e:
    print(e.__context__)
    print(type(e.__context__))
```

Outputs

```
division by zero
<class 'ZeroDivisionError'>
```

To raise the full error  stack only if the catched exception has a context, one could construct something like:

```
try:
    do(0)
except NotImplementedError as e:
    if e.__context__:
        raise e
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, that comes really close to what I need, thanks also for explaining how the initial exception is being masked.

Comment: @Karl I edited the code you added so it's a bit more idiomatic

Answer (score -2):

As the internal structure of the `do()` function is outside of your purview, then I would recommend pre-validation in the form of:

```
if number != 0:
  do(number)
else:
  raise ZeroDivisionError
```

It's hard to say for sure without more bits of the puzzle, but hope that helps.

Comment: I don't have control over do(i), I need to do this in how I wrap exception handling around do(i)

Comment: If the try/except is happening outside of your control, then what you need to pre-validate the input. Wrap it with an `if number != 0:  do(number) else: raise ZeroDivisionError`. Outside of that, I don't know if there is a way to extract secondary and tertiary exceptions from the call stack once the exception is already thrown.